# how to install vtiger crm in localhost

Tags: php, vtiger

Am new to vtiger crm.can any explain how to install vtiger crm and how to create database connection..

i tried to install vtiger crm in localhost but am getting lot errors and workings like

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php
>   on line 373
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php
>   on line 385
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of dbTable::create() should be
>   compatible with that of dbObject::create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 605
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of dbIndex::create() should be
>   compatible with that of dbObject::create() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 769
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of HelpDesk::process_list_query() should
>   be compatible with that of CRMEntity::process_list_query() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\HelpDesk\HelpDesk.php on line 771
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\HelpDesk\HelpDesk.php:771) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\index.php on line 91
>
> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\modules\HelpDesk\HelpDesk.php:771) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\index.php on line 96.

these are some of the errors am getting while try to install vtiger crm..

plz help me..

thanks in Advance..

Comment: your vtiger version? your wamp version?

Comment: XAMPP - 1.7.4  and vtigerCRM 5.3

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running PHP 5.3.x and the version of vtiger you are using is not compatible with 5.3.x

You could either use another php version, or simply supress the errors.

in php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

or you could use a error_reporting from within php

Comment: if i use error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED    my phpmyadmin is not opening

Comment: And if you do it only for your own script, so with
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_STRICT|E_DEPRECATED)); (edited to make it look nicer)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve these errors

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 373

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\vtigercrm\adodb\adodb-xmlschema.inc.php on line 385

$this->indexes[$name] =& new dbIndex( $this, $attributes );//373

$this->data =& new dbData( $this, $attributes );//385
```

in this two lines remove the '&' symbol

```
 $this->indexes[$name] = new dbIndex( $this, $attributes );//373

    $this->data = new dbData( $this, $attributes );//385
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set your PHP to version 5.2 will resolved the same. I have experienced the similar and resolved it by that.